# How to find a specific piece of text in a string with regex and python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a text in every cell of a column, where i want to get some information from. In every cell i have detailed information about cars and i need to get the text from it. In my case these are the fuel and the CO2 information.

The string, that i get, looks like this:

cell 1 = 17.160 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Autogas (LPG), Automatik, HU Neu, 2/3 Türenca. 5,0 l/100km (komb.), ca. 116 g CO₂/km (komb.)

cell 2 = EZ 10/2018, 12.900 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Unfallfrei, Hybrid (Benzin/Elektro), Halbautomatik, HU Neu, ca. 5,9 l/100km (komb.), ca. 134 g CO₂/km (komb.)
... and so on

so i need the information from cell 1: 5,0 l/100 km and 116 g CO2/km

and from cell 2: 5,9 l/100km and 134 g CO2/km

I tried the following code examples, but nothing worked:

```
    pattern_z = re.compile("[a-z]+.?\s?[0-9]+\s?[a-z]?\s[A-Z]+")
    pattern_z = re.compile("^[ac]+\s?[CO]$")
    pattern_z = re.compile(r'[0-9]+.[g]?')
```

and after each "pattern_z" variable i tried

```
    co = pattern_z.search(i)
    cox = co.group()
```

but nothing worked.

I would appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
\b\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\s*l/\d+|\s*g\s+CO₂/)km\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and an optional decimal part
- `(?:` Non catpure group

  - `\s*l/\d+` match `l/` and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\s*g\s+CO₂/` match `g`, whitespace chars and CO₂/
- `)` Close non capture group
- `km\b` Match `km` and a word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cenDKm/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    '17.160 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Autogas (LPG), Automatik, HU Neu, 2/3 Türenca. 5,0 l/100km (komb.), ca. 116 g CO₂/km (komb.)',
    'EZ 10/2018, 12.900 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Unfallfrei, Hybrid (Benzin/Elektro), Halbautomatik, HU Neu, ca. 5,9 l/100km (komb.), ca. 134 g CO₂/km (komb.)'
    ]
pattern = r"\b\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\s*l/\d+|\s*g\s+CO₂/)km\b"
for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['5,0 l/100km', '116 g CO₂/km']
['5,9 l/100km', '134 g CO₂/km']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
(\d+(?:,\d+)?\s*l/\d+km).*?(\d+\s?g\s*CO[₂2]/km)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/3ip4w5/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    l/                       'l/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    km                       'km'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                             (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    g                        'g'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CO                       'CO'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [₂2]               any character of: '&', '#', '8', '3',
                             '2', '2', ';', '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /km                      '/km'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##hZHNSgMxEMfv@xRDT9ka8rHV2gqyaCn2UGxBi6ArkrrpGnY3KUkK6kl68528@SZ9kTVaigdFL/P1Z2Z@zCyf/IPRnaZR9dJYD1ZGkZWFfIRjsC2U5XsoPcLBxWnm2hUNUVnHpJ1@SplLi1AdTG4263VyS4PSiiIvnb9z3oYJLX5IeJdBWWPoBXcFiLM@TC/isarNyiktMZysvCmEAzSensXbtBZelRhGMziXKwwJ7cDl@5uV@l6QzcvrAWbBVpQzVtaASlPPSejcipx3gy1gMAlQ9FvPdKaH18AZTRjvYeAJ6bN/0GZ6IapqYaUKME9zq3JAp1I/K02HlSy9NWHtSFRz8RN6h9r/A7Wz/ysqEEJA6BycAaPDSZdWaQ/ISrJQOg9I6OtHGHa3juOoaT4A)**:

```py
import re

regex = r"(\d+(?:,\d+)?\s*l/\d+km).*?(\d+\s?g\s*CO[₂2]/km)"

test_str = "17.160 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Autogas (LPG), Automatik, HU Neu, 2/3 Türenca. 5,0 l/100km (komb.), ca. 116 g CO₂/km (komb.)\n\nEZ 10/2018, 12.900 km, 80 kW (109 PS)Limousine, Unfallfrei, Hybrid (Benzin/Elektro), Halbautomatik, HU Neu, ca. 5,9 l/100km (komb.), ca. 134 g CO₂/km (komb.) ... and so on"

print (re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

**Results**: `[('5,0\u2009l/100km', '116\u2009g CO₂/km'), ('5,9\u2009l/100km', '134\u2009g CO₂/km')]`